# Buying Nasdaq stocks from outside United States

Tags: stocks, investing, turkey, nasdaq

I want to invest in some companies listed on NASDAQ, but the financial intermediary firms in my country (Turkey) require high commission fees on transactions. Is there a reliable solution to make these international transactions with lower fees?

Comment: interactivebrokers comes to mind

Answer (score 1):

I used to trade on Nasdaq using a US broker from the UK, you need a way to convert your money into US $s and have the cost of international money transfers.

I don’t know if there are any laws in Turkey that will stop you using a US broker.   You are also on your own if anything goes wrong, as the Turkish police will not be interested, and the US police will be very hard to deal with from Turkey.

This all depends on Turkey not unplugging the internet on the day you wish to trade on!!!

(I used tdameritrade, but it was a VERY long timer ago, as UK brokers are now as cheap, you should also consider UK based brokers as they  will also let you trade outside of the USA.)